# selecting values from multiple records in one row but different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table as follows

```
  Ident      type      id   value
   A         CP        1    1000
   A         CP        2    EXIST
   A         GVI       1    100
   A         GVI       2    NOT EXIST
```

I need to view them as follows

```
  Ident   type   value( id=1)  value(ld=2)
    A     CP     1000          Exist
    A     GVI    100           NOT EXIST
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
select Ident, 
       type,
       max(case when id=1 then value end) as [value(ld=1)],
       max(case when id=2 then value end) as [value(ld=2)]
from yourtable
group by Ident,type
```

or You can also use `Pivot` operator

```
SELECT ident, 
       type, 
       [1] AS [value(ld=1)], 
       [2] AS [value(ld=2)] 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   yourtable) A 
       PIVOT (Max(value) 
             FOR id IN ([1], 
                        [2])) pv
```